# Swift Closure why does calling function return error?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

just learning about closures and nesting functions. Given the nested function below:

```
func printerFunction() -> (Int) -> () {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func printInteger(number: Int) {
        runningTotal += 10
        println("The running total is: \(runningTotal)")
    }
    return printInteger
}
```

Why does calling the func itself have an error, but when I assign the func to a constant have no error? Where is printAndReturnIntegerFunc(2) passing the 2 Int as a parameter to have a return value?

```
printerFunction(2) // error
let printAndReturnIntegerFunc = printerFunction() 
printAndReturnIntegerFunc(2) // no error. where is this 2 going??
```

Comment: what kind of error? where it happens?

Comment: cannot invoke 'printerFunction' with an argument list of type '(Int)' - is the error message. I suppose i'm just basically confused why when I assign printerFunction() to a constant, I can pass variables through the constant but I have no idea where that variable actually gets used in the function itself.

Comment: The one-line equivalent of your last two lines is `printerFunction()(2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you are getting error here `printerFunction(2)` because `printerFunction` can not take any argument and If you want to give an argument then you can do it like:

```
func printerFunction(abc: Int) -> (Int) -> (){


}
```

And this will work fine:

```
printerFunction(2)
```

After that you are giving reference of that function to another variable like this:

```
let printAndReturnIntegerFunc = printerFunction()
```

which means the type of `printAndReturnIntegerFunc` is like this:

[image]

that means It accept one `Int` and it will return void so this will work:

```
printAndReturnIntegerFunc(2)
```

Answer (score 5):

(1) The function signature of `printerFunction` is `() -> (Int) -> ()` which means it takes no parameter and returns another function, thats why when you try to call `printerFunction(2)` with a parameter gives you an Error.
(2) And the signature of the returned function is `(Int) -> ()` which means it takes one parameter of Int and returns `Void`. So `printAndReturnIntegerFunc(2)` works